# Arima() in R vs SARIMAX in Python(statmodels) for multivariate forcasting

Tags: python, r, arima, multivariate-time-series, sarimax

I am trying to replicate the results from Arima() in R, using Python for multivariate forecasting. I used SARIMAX in Python with the same p,d,q which I used in Arima(). I was aware that SARIMAX uses 'lbfgs' as the default method while 'bfgs' is used in Arima in R. So I forced the method to be 'bfgs' in SARIMAX. I am still not getting the same results. Can anyone please help me figure this out? or What could be the function that I should use to re-produce the data from Arima() in R?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is the R code :

```
'''
h1 <- dplyr::select(sample_data_dev, x1,x2,x3) %>% as.matrix() 
ts_h <-  ts(sample_data_dev$y,
                start=c(year_start_dev,quarter_start_dev),
                end=c(year_end_dev,quarter_end_dev),
                frequency = 4)

h_model1 <- Arima(y = ts_h, order = c(1,1,1),season = c(0,0,0),xreg = h1) 
h_pred1 <- as_tibble((forecast::forecast(h_model1,
                   xreg=dplyr::select(out_data_forecast[1:h,], x1,x2,x3) %>% s.matrix()))$mean)

'''
```

Here is the python code that I use :

```
'''
import statsmodels.api as sm

dev_start = '1992-06-30'  
dev_end = '2017-12-31'     

date_range = pd.date_range(start= dev_start,end= dev_end,freq= 'Q')

h_data = pd.Series(sample_data_dev['y'],index=date_range)

from statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax import SARIMAX

h_model = SARIMAX(endog = h_data, exog = hel , method = 'bfgs',order = (1,1,1), season = (0,0,0,0))

h_results = h_model.fit()

forecast_steps = h
forecast_x =  out_data_forecast.loc[0:h-1, ['x1','x2','x3']]
 

forcst = h_results.get_forecast(steps = h, exog=forecast_x)
forcst 

forecaset_mean = forcst.predicted_mean
forecaset_mean
'''
```

[image: Here is the plot of results from R and Python]

Comment: How different are the results? Minor differences or big differences in values?

Comment: Can you verify the endo and exog variable data are identical for both models, as far as start / end dates?

Comment: Thanks a lot for trying to help, Jesse. Yes, the inputs for both models are exactly the same. I have updated my question including the plot of results that I got. No big differences. But I need exact same results. If it is not possible, I wonder why. Also my coefficients from R-Arima and Python- SARIMAX are different too.

Comment: Thank you for the plot, that helps. Okay I see now